# Automatic Borrowing in Function Calls

Tags: rust

I'm new to rust and I have a question regarding functions which borrow their arguments.

In C++ a function's type signature alone specifies whether to take an argument by reference; the code which calls the function does not need to explicitly indicate that it is passing a reference. As an example:

```cpp
// The function signature indicates x should be passed by reference.
void increment(int& x) {
    ++x;
}
void main() {
    int y = 0;
    increment(y); // y is implicitly passed by reference
    // y is now 1
}
```

Rust on the other hand does not seem to allow this. The following code will not compile:

```rs
fn output(x: &isize) {
    println!("{}", x);
}

fn main() {
    let y: isize = 0;
    output(y); // Error.
    // output(&y); <- this is ok though
}
```

When using method syntax through, if the function signature takes `&self` or `&mut self` then these borrows happen without the caller using `&` or `&mut`.

Is there a reason that auto-borrowing doesn't happen for general function arguments, and if so why does it happen when using method syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although also written with `&` and frequently called "references", these types in Rust are *pointers* in C++ parlance. They are first-class values, unlike C++ references, and as thus can (and must, in general) be created and dereferenced explicitly.

Accessing fields and methods is a very common operation, however, and often you have `&self`/`&mut self` methods but own the object rather than just having a reference to it, or a reference to a struct whose fields you need to access. Requiring explicitly creating references and dereferencing them in those circumstances would result in a lot of line noise (especially because operator precedence is thus that you'd have to type `(&foo).method()` or `(*foo).field`) for essentially no benefit: Taking a reference is free, and dereferencing to access is deemed worthy of a shortcut even in the spartan C language (`foo->field`). Therefore, when necessary, field access auto-dereferences (including though smart pointers, by the way) and method calls "auto-references".

In other places (e.g. argument passing) this is far less commonly needed, and the explicitness is sometimes valuable for the reader. In general, the compiler can't figure out what you meant. This is exacerbated by the more recently added "deref coercions" where, for example, `&x` for `x: Rc<T>` can result in a `&T` rather than a `&Rc<T>`. There are also tie-breakers for auto-deref but they are pretty clear and generally what you want.

Comment: Your first paragraph doesn’t seem relevant to me. Rust could easily have allowed autoref everywhere; it was a conscious decision not to, because it tends to make code less clear.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan I think I'm mostly trying to describe a better way to think about Rust's references, to set the stage so to speak. I was also getting at the fact that in C++ there's only `T &` and `const T &`, no `T & &` or anything.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding , auto borrow is an ergonomic design

```
struct U;
impl U {
  fn test(&self) {}
}
fn main() {
  let u = U;
  u.test(); // with auto borrow
  (&u).test(); // if without auto borrow , you have to write code like this
}
```